# it is correct to use setup in unit test C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, justmock, arrange-act-assert

I am explaining better, I am studying how to do unit tests in C # with NUnit and justmock. I am reading the book the art of unit tests, Here I am told that whenever possible try to avoid [SetUp] for a previous scenario configuration a try. But googling me on blog that if it's good to use these settings in [SetUp], I'm really confused,
I am aware that if the scenario is very large, the arrange of my test method grows and I have to rafactorizar, Entonce the best elaborate question would be,
When using [SetUp] or if there is some type of pattern when the scenario to test is very large and the Arrange code is affected by this, helpmee???

for example:

```
[TestMethod]
    [Owner("Joaquin")]
    public void Update_CorrectViewDtoAndAllowedUser_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string userName = "johndoe";
        var viewDto = new ViewDto { Id = 1 };
        var view = new View { Id = 1 };

        var authorizationService = Mock.Create<IAuthorizationService>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => authorizationService.GetAccessLevel(viewDto.Id,userName))
            .Returns(AccessLevel.ReadWrite);

        var mapper = Mock.Create<ITypeMapperService>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => mapper.Map<View>(Arg.Is(viewDto)))
            .Returns(view);

        var viewService = Mock.Create<IViewService>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => viewService.GetById(view.Id))
            .Returns(view);

        var viewAppService = CreateViewAppService(viewService, authorizationService, mapper);

        // Act
        var result = viewAppService.Update(viewDto, userName);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
```

Here my arrange is very extensive and I would not want to remove it for a private method or pass it to the [SetUp] there is no pattern to solve this in another way

Comment: what is the 'previous scenario' that you mention in the problem description?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Are you asking when it is appropriate to use the [Setup] tag?

Comment: Also, you can have private helper functions that you can call from `SetUp` so that it doesn't get bloated !

Comment: 1-previous scenario : code in arrange,

Comment: 2- According to Code clean by Robert Cecil Martin, the helpes are just code that you do not know where to put, a class should have a sole responsibility as its methods if you make helpes inside a project, it's like putting functions in a class that The most probable is that it does not have relation with the own class

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with `SetUp` is, that NUnit uses one instance of a `TestFixture` for all tests in it. Changes to the state will be available to all unit tests.

The main problem is, that unit tests have no execution order. The leftover state could break the following unit tests. Errors like that are extremely hard to find. (and may depend on your test environment. Your build server can get different test results, then your local machine).

The usage `SetUp` is no problem, as long you reset all changed state in `TearDown`.

Another alternative is to use XUnit, which does not use the same instance for all tests. The `SetUp` is done in the constructor, and because the class is not reused, no cleanup is needed.

EDIT: But as you stated you are reading "The art of unit testing". The book has nearly a complete chapter on this problem. And will probably explain this a lot better than me ;)